# how to check the cursor type in java?

Tags: java, windows, cursor

In Windows OS is it possible to check the cursor type ?

if yes then how can I determine that whether the cursor type is text cursor or not, using java?

Comment: Had you heard of [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) ? Along with this seems like you need to go through the [WIN-32 API](http://search.cpan.org/~cosimo/Win32-API-0.68/API.pm). Here are the [Tutorials for Win-API](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/)

Comment: Why on Earth do you think you need to know?  If you want a particular cursor, set it.  If you want to know when a component is focused, add a `FocusListener. If you want to know when the mouse is over a component, add a `MouseListener`.  What did I miss?

Comment: May be i've missed my purpose. i need this bcz - i want detect the textfield of another application running in windows. That means when I want to insert something in a text field, cursor type normally become text cursor. This way i can detect the text field and perform some additional action. @Andrew Thompson

Comment: OK, none of the techniques I proposed would fulfill your use-case.  What you are trying to do is a very fragile way to perform a very suspicious (from a security P.O.V.) action.  What is the other application, specifically?

Comment: yes, because there is no other solution in my mind. I have a system (don't have any access in code level) which runs i PC without mouse or keyboard, only touch screen monitor as input. In this application i have to show an onscreen keyboard when a user press in the textfield. For this i have to detect the cursor and show the onscreen keyboard when it is text cursor. Do you have any other/better solution for this situation ? If Yes then please ...  @Andrew Thompson

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use java's [Cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html) class to get the type of cursor.

Take a look at [Cursor.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#getName%28%29) for your task.

Example Code:

```
Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
System.out.println(cursor.getName());
System.out.println(cursor.getType());
```

Output = `Default Cursor
0`

I f you take a look at [Cursor.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/Cursor.java.html). It mentions that

```
/**
   52        * The default cursor type (gets set if no cursor is defined).
   53        */
   54       public static final int     DEFAULT_CURSOR                  = 0;
```

So, I believe you have to mention the cursor type manually in your java code.

Comment: Thanks, but it always shows "Default Cursor 0". what about the other cursors or Text Cursor ?

Comment: @fean: Sorry I don't have much idea about the cursor class. Take a look at my edit.